# Problema com matrizes em C

Tags: c, matriz

Tenho que fazer um programa que vai ler 4 notas de cada um dos 6 alunos de uma turma e armazená-las em uma matriz NOTAS[6][5]. Para cada aluno, deve-se calcular a média aritmética das 4 notas e armazenar esta média na última coluna da matriz (coluna de índice 4). O programa também deve imprimir a média de cada aluno e, por fim, a média aritmética da turma.

Fiz um código e fui executar, na hora de pegar o ALUNO 6 NOTA 2, em vez de ser digitado ALUNO 6, ele digita um número totalmente aleatório, e acaba o programa, e dependendo, o código da erros diferentes!

Qual erro estou cometendo?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
float nota[6][5], media;
int i, j;
media = 0;

for(i=1; i<=6; i++) {
    for(j=1; j<=5; j++) {
        printf("\nAluno %d Nota %d \n", i, j);
        scanf("%f", &nota[i][j]);
    }
}

for(i=1;i<=6;i++)
    {
    for(j=1;j<= 5;j++) {
        printf("%f", nota[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<5; j++) {
        nota[i][5] = nota[i][5] + nota[i][j];
    }
}

for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {
    nota[i][5] = nota[i][5]/4;
    media = nota[i][5] + media;
}

media = media/6;
for(i=0; i<=6; i++) {
    printf("\nA média do aluno %d = %.2f", i, nota[i][5]);
}
printf("\nA média dos alunos: %.2f", media);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todos os loops estão com índices errados.

primeiro loop

```
int n_alunos = 6;
int n_notas = 4;
for(i=0; i != n_alunos; i++) {
  for(j=0; j != n_notas; j++) {
    printf("\nAluno %d Nota %d \n", i, j);
    scanf("%f", &nota[i][j]);
  }
}
```

O valor inicial da soma tem que ser zero.

```
int j_media = 4;
for(i = 0; i != n_alunos; ++i)
{
  nota[i][j_media] = 0.0;
}
```

Soma das notas e média

```
for(i=0; i != n_alunos; ++i) {
  // soma das notas
  for(j = 0; j != n_notas; j++) {
    nota[i][j_media] = nota[i][j_media] + nota[i][j];
  }
  // média do aluno
  nota[i][j_media] = nota[i][j_media] / n_notas;
}
```

média da turma

```
for(i = 0; i!=n_alunos; i++) {
  media = nota[i][j_media] + media;
}
media = media / n_alunos;
```

os loops de saída ficam por sua conta.

Answer (score 1):

Em C as o `for` jamais deve começar em **1** e ir até **N** quando se trabalha com vetores e matrizes, pois o tamanho do vetor ou da matriz vai de **0** até **N-1**.

Caso tenha uma matriz 6x5, sou `for` o i deve ir de **0** a **5** e o j de **0** a **4**.

O erro é porque você certamente está tentando escrever em uma posição inexistente da sua matriz.

Comment: Arrumei os for, e mesmo assim está dando números aleatórios, sendo que para todos alunos, usei a mesma nota e deu valores diferentes e mesmo e também usando o %.2f para a média de todos os alunos, parece que a formatação foi anulada.                                       A média do aluno 0 = 3,75
A média do aluno 1 = 11,25
A média do aluno 2 = 15,25
A média do aluno 3 = 20,75
A média do aluno 4 = 1636992022601586400000000000000000,00
A média dos alunos: 272832003766931070000000000000000,00